# How not to duplicate the IHostedService .Net core 2.2 in scalable microservices?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I have a subtask with `IHostedService` in my API and I have a question.

How can I do that whenever there is a new instance in Azure, this service will not be duplicated?

It is a process that sends daily emails. If this doubles then my clients may end up receiving two identical emails.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(provider => new SendScheduledReportsService(provider.CreateScope()));
```

Comment: What about moving logic with sheduledReports to separate WebJob or Azure function?

Comment: In what cases the service will be scalledup?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it doesn't matter. Well written code should not work incorrectly in case of scalling.

Comment: The code is the same so it will be executed the same way in all the instances and it will do the duplicate job if it is not written to avoid it. Autoscaling can not control this. So my suggestion would be to handle this in code so that autoscalling does not trigger duplicates.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: wouldn't one store the state of sent emails in a database or so? This is not only subject of scaling, but also of crashing, restarting etc.

Comment: @ThomasWeller It can be any approach to track whether the scheduled task is completed/failed/retried etc. Not only autoscalling, restarting the service also would attempt to do the same job again if it does not know what happened to the scheduled task. So yes, tracking is needed.

Comment: @Maris
Yes we could do a webJob or a function, thanks for the indication. I was just looking for a simpler way to do it, because it is a very simple job. But I will consider this solution! Thank you!

Comment: @GersonReis if it's a simple job, don't create two of them. The question contains very little useful information - `microservices` is a fashion term, you have daemons/services/processes. Why would you need *more* than one instance of that process? Is it too heavy? For reliability? Load balancing? Something else? The answer to that matters a *lot*. For load balancing you could use one instance for half the customers, another one for the other half. If one goes down, you lose the emails, just as you would now.

Comment: If you want reliability, you need to track which messages were sent to whom, eg in a table or using a queue. Nothing specific to "microservices" here either.

Comment: If you use Hangfire to schedule the jobs, queuing, tracking etc are already handled.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos 
As I said in the announcement, the application can scale and have new instabilities. The question is that even if she duplicates the application, I don't want my tasks to duplicate.

The microservice reference was because it really is a small and scalable service.

I will do a web job as you mentioned in other comments. Thank you.

Comment: @GersonReis I read the question. It's ambiguous and doesn't explain what you mean by "scale". Scale is not the same as "duplicate" - why should the application be duplicated? Even if it is, why should it handle the *same* customers? You don't need a web job just two ensure that two service instances work with different data. Web apps used multiple instances for load balancing for decades before web jobs came abougt

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks for your point of view, it really helped me to analyze the situation better. I will consider your comments.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
I'm still in doubt, as the subtask only sends a few scheduled emails.

The purpose of the application is to make simple and small reports, and the user can schedule to receive this daily by email in addition to being able to view it in the application itself. (If this wepp app reaches its limit, we will have one more instance of it.)

Comment: The point is that today I have not implemented a scheme to change what was processed or not, because it was really simple and updated a field that tells us the last date of shipment.

Comment: Now with this conversation, I see that I can make a check in this date field, and so I don't worry about the fact that I have one more instance of the application, even if this event happens, the processing would be distributed.

Comment: Or do a web job as Meris commented above. But I believe I would have one more application to take care of ...